# How to maintain same folder structure in github with git commands

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push

I want to `track` my project folder and its subfolder with `node modules` together with `git add`.

But it seems I can't push from my `parent` to git .

How can I commit my changes into same `repository` ?

What I am facing issue here if I push from parent the `client` folder is not updating for the first time. 
If I make commit from `clint` the parent is removed fully from my git.
What changes i needs to make here.

any suggestion.

//gitignore.

```
node_modules
package-lock.json
.env
```

[image: Folder structure]

Comment: It looks like you have 2 repositories. Can you check if : a. `parent/.git` exists and is a directory, b. `parent/client/.git` exists and is a directory ?

Comment: @LeGEC thank you for your response. I have only one repository. how could I maintain both here. As its a MERN project.